# AJAX based Auction House

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i am adding a auction section to my website , i can easily make a php version, however i wanted to make it look a bit better. I want for it to reload automatically, in other words the user sits there and watch all the other bids, new listings etc... happen infront of them without reloading the page.

Is it possible to do this with AJAX or Jquery.

Any tips or tutorials would greatly help me, i have had a look on google but have not found much close enough to what i want.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately this isn't the correct forum for your question. Please try to limit your questions here to those that have specific correct answers. The above question is more likely to lead to open-ended debate.

Comment: Yes, this can probably be moved to Programmers. Anyway, while using `xmlhttprequest` you should consider using HTML5 `WebSockets` for your application. Look em up ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Assuming that you know jQuery, the nature of AJAX requests and you want a live "stream" of the data for your auction, you might want to consider [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) methods of retrieving live data

Answer (score 0):

It possible (and recommended) to do this with AJAX in jQuery.

See the [jQuery AJAX api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for *tips*.